# QTableView with icons in rows

Tags: c++, qt, icons, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` showing rows of a database table. In this table I have a column called data type and I have icon images for each type. How can I add these icons in front of each data type?

Here's a part of my code as requested by *justanothercoder*.

```
QString msgQueryString = "select MESSAGE_ID, DATA_TYPE from SER_MESSAGES where MESSAGE_ID > 500 ";
serendibMsgTableModel->setQuery(msgQueryString, *database);
serendibMsgTableModel->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Message ID"));
serendibMsgTableModel->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Data Type"));

serendibMsgProxyModel->setSourceModel(serendibMsgTableModel);
serendibMsgView->setModel(serendibMsgProxyModel);
```

"serendibMsgTableModel" is a `QSqlQueryModel` and "serendibMsgProxyModel" is a customized `QSortFilterProxyModel`. "serendibMsgView" is the `QTableView` I need the icons to be displayed, in the Data Type column.

Hope this helps for your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the *DecorationRole* of your items to the QPixmap you want and it should work.

edit:

I guess that the icon depends on the value in the data type column.

```
int rowCount = serendibMsgTableModel->rowCount();

for(int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
{
    QModelIndex index = serendibMsgTableModel->index(row, 1);
    QVariant value = serendibMsgTableModel->data(index);
    static QPixmap s_invalidIcon(PATH_TO_INVALID_ICON);
    static QPixmap s_type1Icon(PATH_TO_TYPE1_ICON);
    static QPixmap s_type2Icon(PATH_TO_TYPE2_ICON);

    QPixmap icon(s_invalidIcon);

    if(value.toString() == "type1")
    {
        icon = s_type1Icon;
    }
    else if(value.toString() == "type2")
    {
        icon = s_type2Icon;
    }
    serendibMsgTableModel->setData(index, icon, Qt::DecorationRole);
}
```

Something like this should work.
Set the values before setModel.

I haven't tested it, but I think you should get the idea from this.

Comment: Thanks justanothercoder. But I need a little more detailed description than that since I'm absolutely new to Qt. I'm learning Qt as I'm developing this application.

Comment: I'm a bit unaware of where to begin, you need to add a bit more description of what you have done. Adding some source code to the question might be good.

Comment: I have modified the original question and added a code snippet.

Comment: Thank u very much justanothercoder. I'll try this n let u know how it went. :)

Answer (score 9):

I saw that you've already picked an answer but since you are learning Qt I'll add a few things.

Taking a look at the excellent Qt documentation I suggest you overwrite this in your model:

```
QVariant QSqlTableModel::data ( 
            const QModelIndex & index,
            int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const   [virtual]
```

There are various **roles** (int role = Qt::DisplayRole):

> **enum Qt::ItemDataRole** :
>   Each item in the model has a set of
>   data elements associated with it, each
>   with its own role. The roles are used
>   by the view to indicate to the model
>   which type of data it needs. Custom
>   models should return data in these
>   types.
>
> **Qt::DecorationRole** : The data to be
>   rendered as a decoration in the form
>   of an icon. (QColor, QIcon or Qpixmap)

Thus, what you need to do is return a QIcon or QPixmap in the data() function for the DisplayRole.

Another approach which might be more appropriate is to make use of **delegates**: For example [ColorListEditor](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/itemviews-coloreditorfactory-colorlisteditor-cpp.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Derick. In fact, I had a feeling I could use delegates for this task, and I've been trying out some examples as well. Thanks for your example as well.

Comment: Quoting: "Thus, what you need to do is return a QIcon or QPixmap in the data() function for the DisplayRole." ... did you mean `DisplayRole` or `DecorationRole`?